# What is the difference between stream.end and stream.destroySoon for files in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing to a file (a writable steam) and I need to close the file once I'm done. I'm not sure of the difference between these two functions or if I need to call them both. Here's what the documentation says:

```
stream.end()
```

Terminates the stream with EOF or FIN. This call will allow queued write data to be sent before closing the stream.

```
stream.destroySoon()
```

After the write queue is drained, close the file descriptor. `destroySoon()` can still destroy straight away, as long as there is no data left in the queue for writes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference.

From fs.js in the node source:

```
// There is no shutdown() for files.
WriteStream.prototype.destroySoon = WriteStream.prototype.end;
```